# adding a php code in

Tags: php, input, tags

I need some help to put a simple php tag in this code

```
$return.="<form method='post' action='#'><input type='submit' value=''><input type='hidden' name='task'></form>";
```

I need to put the php - `<?php echo $htmlString; ?>` - in the first input tag

Can somebody help please?

Thanks

Comment: where exactly do you want to insert it? As value in Submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert it as value to submit button here is the solution.

```
$return.="<form method='post' action='#'><input type='submit' value='$htmlString'><input type='hidden' name='task'></form>";
```

**Update**:
Use the following code: as you want to use the variable CbText::_('CONFIRM').

```
$return.="<form method='post' action='#'><input type='submit' value='" . CbText::_('CONFIRM') . "'><input type='hidden' name='task'></form>";
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but I need it to be like I wrote exactly "<?php echo $htmlString; ?>" because I have one more input and there I will put <?php echo CbText::_('CONFIRM');?> (this is for multilingual translate) ... so I basicaly need the php code "<?php echo CbText::_('CONFIRM');?>" in that input.. I tried to put it in different ways but it always gives me some error .. can you help please?

Comment: use the following code: 
`$return.="<form method='post' action='#'><input type='submit' value='" . CbText::_('CONFIRM') . "'><input type='hidden' name='task'></form>";`

Comment: Awesome! I'll update my answer as per your new requirements. Merry Christmas!!

Answer (score 2):

```
 $return.="<form method='post' action='#'><input type='submit' value='$htmlString'><input type='hidden' name='task'></form>";
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but I need it to be like I wrote exactly "<?php echo $htmlString; ?>" because I have one more input and there I will put <?php echo CbText::_('CONFIRM');?> (this is for multilingual translate) ... so I basicaly need the php code "<?php echo CbText::_('CONFIRM');?>" in that input.. I tried to put it in different ways but it always gives me some error .. can you help please?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, or if I do, if it is a smart move. You'll end up with a PHP String with that exact text in it. What will you do then? save it as a .php file? Run it trough EVAL? Because if you ECHO it, it will not be parsed again in a default environment!

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not too good in this stuff sorry can't explain well, but the code from Echo will go in a file (where all the translations are) and I'm writing the code from echo which for example is CONFIRM , and give it a value like this CONFIRM=CONFERME (depends on file, each file one language)..

Comment: Please don't bother any more, Virendra helped with the code, it's like this - $return.="<form method='post' action='#'><input type='submit' value='" . CbText::_('CONFIRM') . "'><input type='hidden' name='task'></form>";

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

- You can print HTML code conditionally with PHP using this syntax:

  ```
  <?php

  // Your code

  ?>

  <form method='post' action='#'>
    <input type='submit' value='<?php echo $htmlString; ?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='task'>
  </form>

  <?php

  // Your code

  ?>
  ```
- Or just by string concatenation:

  ```
  $return .= "<form method='post' action='#'>";
  $return .= "<input type='submit' value='$htmlString'>";
  $return .= "<input type='hidden' name='task'></form>";
  ```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but I need it to be like I wrote exactly "<?php echo $htmlString; ?>" because I have one more input and there I will put <?php echo CbText::_('CONFIRM');?> (this is for multilingual translate) ... so I basicaly need the php code "<?php echo CbText::_('CONFIRM');?>" in that input.. I tried to put it in different ways but it always gives me some error .. can you help please?